# SQL for spatial view of line start/end points (Oracle ST_GEOMETRY)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

**How do I create a spatial view that generates dynamic point geometry of the start point and end point of a line feature class?**

I have successfully made a similar view that is a buffer of a line feature class with this SQL:

```
SELECT OBJECTID, SDE.ST_BUFFER(SHAPE, 1) AS LINE_BUFFER FROM ENG.ROAD
```

I thought I'd be able to use similar SQL to generate start points of lines using the [PointN](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/a-quick-tour-of-sql-functions-used-with-st-geometry.htm)  function:

```
SELECT OBJECTID, SDE.ST_POINTN(SHAPE, 1) AS START_POINT FROM ENG.ROAD
```

The view creates successfully, however it only creates a tabular view, not a spatial view. What have I done wrong?

I'm also unsure how to get the end point index position, but I'm not even thinking about that yet.

Comment: What does the documentation say the ST_PointN function returns?  If it isn't an ST_Geometry, then that would explain that.  The documentation also shows an ST_EndPoint function.  So now you can look for a function to convert a ST_Point object to ST_Geometry, and you'll be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vince suggested, the query needed to return ST_Geometry, not ST_Point:

```
SELECT OBJECTID, SDE.ST_GEOMETRY (SDE.ST_ASTEXT (SDE.ST_STARTPOINT (SHAPE)),300049) 
    AS START_POINT 
FROM ENG.ROAD
```

I'm surprised how many functions were needed to convert from lines to endpoints. I would have thought there would have been a single function to go from ST_Point to ST_Geometry, but the only way I could find to do it was to throw ST_ASTEXT in the middle. The view is quite slow, probably because of this.

**Update:**

There's an ESRI/Oracle bug that prevents query layers from successfully using ST_POINT in Arcmap:

[Bug: Unable to define a query layer in ArcGIS where the data source uses an st_geometry subtype in Oracle](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011333)

[Get ArcMap to recognize ST_POINT (SDE.ST_GEOMETRY)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218558/how-to-get-arcmap-to-recognize-st-point-sde-st-geometry)

The bug explains why I'm having problems. If ArcMap query layers were able to recognize ST_POINT like they're supposed to, then this question would be unnecessary.