# Get ArcGIS to recognize ST_POINT

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, spatial-view

I have a SDE.ST_GEOMETRY line feature class. I've created a view on it that returns an `st_point` column.

```
SELECT OBJECTID, SDE.ST_STARTPOINT(SHAPE) AS START_POINT FROM ENG.ROAD
```

There is a known Oracle bug that is preventing me from using my view : [Unable to define a query layer in ArcGIS where the data source uses an st_geometry subtype in Oracle](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011333).

The bug description states:

> ...the binding used in Oracle to fetch the geometry binds an
> st_geometry type. Because the attribute or values returned from the
> attribute do not map to st_geometry, the Oracle internal error is
> encountered. By definition, a type binding should support its subtype
> definitions. This limitation is currently a bug within Oracle's
> server.

The workaround is:

> Convert the geometry attribute field from the subtype (for example,
> st_point) to the supertype st_geometry.

However, it doesn't say *how* to do the conversion; I don't know how to convert from the subclass to the superclass.

**Question:**

How can I get ArcMap to recognize an ST_POINT subclass column?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48950/discussion-on-question-by-wilson-how-to-get-sde-st-geometry-points-to-show-up-in).

Comment: In fact SDE have it own geometry type. In SQL Server it reconnize has custom type. I don't think you can Cast this because this is two differents schema. so you need pass data as text format. Look at [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-geometry.htm#ESRI_SECTION3_3A79DF2265424C6E982BA56056A8A438) you can create function to pass data sdo to sde and reverse.

Comment: Note: I don't get the error in ArcGIS Pro. I only get the error in ArcMap. So I guess  Pro is better at handling ST_POINTs than ArcMap. With that said, both ArcMap and Pro have a problem where they crash when trying to export the data to a FGDB. I talk about that issue in my answer about the TREAT() function.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an SDE to play with. I think you would have to do something like this:

```
With point As (
 select sde.st_point (10.01, 20.03, 4326) as pt from dual
)
select sde.st_geometry(sde.ST_X(p.pt), sde.ST_Y(p.pt), sde.ST_Z(p.pt), sde.ST_M(p.pt), sde.ST_SRID(p.pt)) as ptGeom 
 from point p;
```

Or you could use WKB.

My packages and objects have implementations of ST_StartPoint that return SDO_GEOMETRY objects. 
You could create a function that does the same thing but return a point geometry:

```
create function ST_Point2Geom(p_pt in sde.st_point)
returns sde.st_geometry deterministic
As
begin
  return case when p_pt is null 
              then null 
              when sde.ST_GeometryType(p_pt) <> 'ST_POINT'
              then p_pt 
              else sde.st_geometry(sde.ST_X(p_pt), sde.ST_Y(p_pt),
                                   sde.ST_Z(p_pt), sde.ST_M(p_pt),
                                   sde.ST_SRID(p_pt)) 
          end;
end st_point2geom;
/
show errors

select st_point2Geom(sde.st_startPoint(myGeom)) from dual;
```

Comment: Exacty that i speak about in comment! I think you proposed a good solution to workaround.

Comment: other sotultion can be use TO_CHAR and remade point in native ST_POINT

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, Oracle's [TREAT()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TREAT.html#GUID-037C0CD3-C256-4A02-80E0-C6F15147C5BF) function seems to help:

```
select
    treat(  sde.st_pointonsurface(sde.st_buffer(shape,0.05)  ) as sde.st_geometry) as midpoint 
from
    active_transportation
```

When I use TREAT(), I don't get the error as often when adding the layer to ArcMap.

---

**Edit:**

In a reply to [Create NIL (zero vertex) geometry](https://community.esri.com/t5/geodatabase-questions/create-nil-zero-vertex-geometry/m-p/1352208/highlight/true#M8691), I mention that [the bug](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/bug-unable-to-define-a-query-layer-in-arcgis-where-the-000011333) has been updated. It now suggests that we use the [st_geometry constructor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-geometry.htm) to convert from subtypes to supertypes. Which seems to work for converting [SDE.ST_POLYFROMTEXT] to [SDE.ST_GEOMETRY].

But that doesn't seem to help me when converting [ST_POINT] subtype to [ST_GEOMETRY] supertype:

[image]